# Javascript library/plugin for range calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I was wondering if someone know a library to solve this problem: (I al already googled)

Given I have the following product quantity range object:

```
[
    {
       start:1,
       end: 10,
       unitPrice: 100,
    },
    {
       start:11,
       end: 20,
       unitPrice: 80,
    },
    {
       start:21,
       end: 0,
       unitPrice: 60,
    }
]
```

This means a progressive discount is configured, and from 21 or more the unitPrice is the same.

In the client side I have fields and a table that display those ranges with a javascript based UI.

When another range is added the table must be recreated with some special calculations, for instance:

Table A:

```
start   end   unitPrice
0       10    100
11      20    80
21      -     60
```

When I add to Table A start: 5, end: 15 and price 90, table should look as follows:

```
start   end   unitPrice
0       4     100
5       15    90
16      20    80
21      -     60
```

When I add to Table A start: 50, end: 0 and price 50, table should look as follows:

```
start   end   unitPrice
0       10    100
11      20    80
21      49    60
50      -     50
```

When I add to Table A start: 7, end: 60 and price 50, table should look as follows:

```
start   end   unitPrice
0       6    100
7       -    50
```

When I add to Table A start: 7, end: 60 and price 65, table should look as follows:

```
start   end   unitPrice
0       6    100
7       60   65
61      -    60  (because it was the lowest value on the existing table)
```

If no libraries, whats the best logical way to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: I don't need to sort or order the table, I need to calculate the inputed range combination

Comment: It is a lot more than sorting/ordering, check out the API

Comment: I know that it does and I use it in my projects. I would be glad if you can point where you found a plugin or a native API method or datatables example to handle that ranging that's better and more flexible than using native javascript ou jquery plugin. I'm generating a object converting it to an array and then using datatables to generate the table.